# Telegram Bots: Encoding Plus Character / Plus Sign

Tags: character-encoding, telegram-bot

I am working on a telegram bot which sends telephone numbers to my telegram account. The problem is, that a '+' is converted to a ' ' blank. So every telephone number is wrong. 

E.g. '+4915733000000' turns into '4915733000000'. I've tried to use the HTML code &#43 the unicode version \u002B and the url encoding caracter %2B and none of them work.

```
https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=MYID&text=Test:\u2031 Unicode:\u002B HTML:&#43; URL:%2B
```

Result: Test:‱ Unicode: HTML:

Do you know any possiblility to send a plus sign?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is using VBA to send Telegram messages with + in them you can replace your string like that:

```
Dim URL as String
Dim reURL as String

URL = "https://www.webpage.com/product+name/specifics+number" 'etc....
reURL = replace(URL, "+, "%2B")

'send message to telegram code here
```

For more Encoding info you can visit: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send the plus sign using POST method.

Here's the sample Google App Script code (can be easily adapted to JavaScript).

```
var options = {
  method : "post",
  payload: {
    method: "sendMessage",
    chat_id: "<chat_id_here>",
    text: "+something",
    parse_mode: "HTML"
  }
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot<YOUR_TOKEN>/", options);
```

---

Plus sign can also be easily sent with parse_mode="Markdown".
Just checked (this time on Python using telebot library) that both options work:

```
bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, "Phone number: +1234567890", parse_mode='Markdown')
bot.send_message(CHAT_ID, "Phone number: +1234567890", parse_mode='HTML')
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it's a working solution. Edited the answer and added some information there.

Comment: This is absolutely correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using Java and Spring's WebClient. The only way to make it work is building `WebClient` using `DefaultUriBuilderFactory` and set encoding mode to `NONE`.

```
DefaultUriBuilderFactory factory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(url);
factory.setEncodingMode(DefaultUriBuilderFactory.EncodingMode.NONE);
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().uriBuilderFactory(factory).filter(logRequest()).build();
```

Default is `EncodingMode.TEMPLATE_AND_VALUES` so if you replace `+` with `%2B` the resulting URL is %252B. Setting the encoding mode to `NONE` doesn't replace any especial characters so I had to replace them manually.

```
private String replaceUrlSpecialCharacters(String message) {
    return message.replace("%", "%25").replace("+", "%2B").replace(" ", "%20").replace("|", "%7C").replace(System.lineSeparator(), "%0A");
}
```

And now the `+` sign is shown in my messages.

Answer (score 0):

I'am using PHP and this case was solved with rawurlencode. Below is the code:

```
public function send_message($tg_msg)
{
    $tg_token = ''; // Bot Token
    $chat_id = ''; // Chat ID
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $tg_token . '/sendMessage?parse_mode=markdown&chat_id=' . $chat_id;
    $curlopt_url = $url . '&text=' . rawurlencode($tg_msg);
    $ch = curl_init();
    $optArray = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $curlopt_url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    );
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

$msg = 'The message';
send_message($msg);
```

And now the + sign is shown in my messages.

Answer (score 0):

I got that solved by just using this php function:

```
utf8_encode(text_to_send)
```